# Azure Service Bus getting disabled

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We are observing a peculiar issue in one of our service bus. We have topic and subscription setup and a webjob listens to the subscription. However, whenever the webjob runs it disables the topic and we trying to troubleshoot this issue. We have this same job (bits) running in all our lower environments and have not observed this issue. What would be the possible approach to troubleshoot this issue?

> e = {"Messaging entity 'xxxxx-hub:Topic:integrationtopic~175|xxx' is
>   currently disabled.
>   TrackingId:dff41ae0-ba6d-49ec-a097-83f7d73be57c_G2_B0,
>   SystemTracker:xxxx-hub:topic:integrationtopic~175|xxx,
>   Timestamp:11/23/2017 10:54:54 AM"}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code is identical, you should open a support issue with Microsoft as it's not a normal behaviour on Azure Service Bus.

For the sake of sanity, would help to see your webjob code.